# How can I place a comment in Facebook Open Graph API post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I create posts using Facebook Open Graph API with custom action. These posts are displayed in Timeline with caption "User Name added a visit..." ("add" and "visit" are my custom action and object), then a block with image, title and description.

I create a post sending HTTP POST request to Facebook with only a link to page. Facebook fetches data from this page from meta tags og:type, og:url, og:title, og:image, og:description.

I want to place a text between caption "User Name added a visit..." and image. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of what part of the action you're trying to update? Are you sure you're not thinking of the `message` parameter? - the criteria for approval for use of the message parameter are documented on the OG documentation (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/ )

Comment: Do you mean that I should send `message` parameter with link to page in POST request to Facebook? Sorry, I don't understand about screenoshot. There is a link to [example post](http://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=469322056445914&id=100001043710814). It was auto posted by Flickr. I want to add user comment between user name and photo thumb. It is possible because other apps can do it (Instagram, for example).

Comment: Thanks, @Igy I made a test with `message` parameter in POST request to Facebook and it created post as I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'message' parameter in your open graph call. The text in this key will be shown in the place where you want.